# How to query a DataSet and set the result as a DataSource for some control? (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, ienumerable

I'm digging in in my Microsoft Visual Studio Documentation and I found this article under C# Reference (ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/dv_csref/html/df01e266-5781-4aaa-80c4-67cf28ea093f.htm), It's about `Interface Interface`. Here's the example code:

```
class SelectSample1
{   
    static void Main()
    {           
        //Create the data source
        List<int> Scores = new List<int>() { 97, 92, 81, 60 };

        // Create the query.
        IEnumerable<int> queryHighScores =
            from score in Scores
            where score > 80
            select score;

        // Execute the query.
        foreach (int i in queryHighScores)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " ");
        }            
    }
}
//Output: 97 92 81
```

Instead of a `List`, is it also possible to query a `DataTable` and set the result of the query as the DataSource of a `DataGridView`?
If yes, suppose I have this structure:

```
Fruit       |   CategoryID
---------------------------------------
Lemon       |   1
Orange      |   1
Apple       |   2
Pear        |   2
```

Can anyone please give me an example (if possible, for a beginner's approach.. :). What I want is to display the result in a DataGridView. Display all fruits where its CategoryID is equal to 1. Please help,

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) extension of Databe to select the rows and bind to DataGridView like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Fruit");
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Lemon", 1 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Orange", 1 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Apple", 2 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Pear", 2 });

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                           where row.Field<int>("ID") == 1
                           select new {Fruit = row.Field<string>("Fruit"), ID = row.Field<int>("ID")};

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var results = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
where row.Field<int>("CategoryID") == 1
select row ;
```

and you can bind the result row easily to your control.